# R: How to get my for loop to print a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I need my for loop to output a vector instead of just a series of answers. Here is my code:

```
mean=211
sd=sqrt(558)
x=rnorm(100,mean,sd)
cost=40

for(i in c(1:100))
{
    if(x[i]<=200)
    {
        profit=x[i]-cost
    }
    else
    {
        profit=200-cost
    }
print(profit)
}
```

How do I get it to print the different profits as one vector?

Comment: I think you want `pmax(x, 200) - cost`, fwiw.

Comment: @Frank   I think that it is really `pmin(x,200) - cost`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've changed it to pmin inside the for loop instead of the if and else but still can't get a vector output?

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you can just start with `profit_array <- numeric(length(x))` and then in the FOR-loop:

- after `profit=x[i]-cost` add a new line with `profit_array[i] <- profit`
- after `profit = 200-cost` add a new line with `profit_array[i] <- profit`
- finally, `print(profit_array)` should do the trick

Hope this helps!

Edit: actually some of the comments are much more efficient. You can bypass the whole FOR-loop by using vectorized code: `profit <- pmin(x, 200) - cost`.